# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:A TCP error(10049: The requested address is not valid in its context) How to use a VM of Azure as Server

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-virtual-machine

I´m trying to do that, a VM of azure was my server.
I´m using C# on Visual Studio with WCF.
My app.config of the Host is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="TimbiricheService.UserManagerService">
        <endpoint address="UserManagerService" binding="netTcpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="" contract="TimbiricheService.IUserManager" />
        <endpoint address="UserManagerService" binding="netTcpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="" contract="TimbiricheService.IManagerOnlineUsers" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://20.81.133.87:8082" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://20.81.133.87:8081" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
</configuration>
```

and my VM has the next specs:
[image: image of VM IPs]

and the next rules
[image: image of VM rules]

And also i have deactivated the firewall of the VM

When i run the host, it throw the next excepction on the line host.open();

```
namespace TimbiricheHost
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TimbiricheService.UserManagerService)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Server is running");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=A TCP error (10049: The requested address is not valid in its context) occurred while listening on IP Endpoint=20.81.133.87:8081.
  Source=System.ServiceModel
  StackTrace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionListener.Listen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ExclusiveTcpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpChannelListener`2.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
   at TimbiricheHost.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\timbiriche\Documents\GitHub\Timbiriche-The-Game\Timbiriche-Service\TimbiricheHost\Program.cs:line 16

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
SocketException: The requested address is not valid in its context
```

HOW CAN I FIX IT?

Because if i put the private ip on the base address it works, but with the public ip it doesn´t works

I already disabled the firewall, add the rules of inbounds and outbounds ports on Azure, and the previous things tha i commented on before.